# "socketIO_client not found" and "cannot import sql related function" error when running "github sadit" software in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, python3, python-2.7, sql

I am trying to run 'github sadit'  software in Ubuntu 12.04. It requires to install python `socket.io` and `socketIO-clients`. I have python 2.7.3, python 3.2.3, python-dev installed and for `socket.io` and `socketIO-clients`  I use this command in terminal `npm install socket.io` and the output of the command can be seen in this website: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23215384/. Then I try to run software but software shows the following:

[image]

So it's showing `socketIO_client not found` and `cannot import sql related function`. How to solve these errors?